# How to mimic URI query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

This may be too basic of a question for SO, but I thought I would ask anyway.

I getting my feet wet with ElasticSearch and am trying to return a single document that has an exact match to my field of interest.

I have the field "StoryText" which is mapped as ***type "string"*** and **indexed as "not_analyzed".**

When I search using a the basic URI query:

```
123.456.0.789:9200/stories/storyphrases/_search?q=StoryText:"The boy sat quietly"
```

I return an exact matched document as I expected with a single hit.

However, when I use the search functionality:

```
GET 123.456.0.789:9200/stories/storyphrases/_search

{
"query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "filter" : {
            "term" : {
                "StoryText" : "The boy sat quietly"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get multiple documents returned with many hits (i.e. "The boy sat loudly", "The boy stood quietly" etc. etc.)

Could somebody help me to understand how I need to restructure my search request to mimic the result I get using the basic query parameter?

At present I am using NEST in C# to generate my search request which looks like this

```
var searchresults = client.Search<stories>(p => p
    .Query(q => q
        .Filtered(r => r
            .Filter(s => s.Term("StoryText", inputtext))
            )
        )
    );
```

Thanks very much for any and all reads and or thoughts!

---

UPDATE:  Mappings are listed below

```
GET /stories/storyphrases/_mappings

{
"stories": {
    "mappings": {
        "storyphrases": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_optional_time"
                },
                "@version": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "SubjectCode": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "VerbCode": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "LocationCode": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "BookCode": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Route": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "StoryText": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "SourceType": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "host": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "message": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "path": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mick

Comment: Is your `StoryText` field definitely not analyzed? Can you post your mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off you are executing two different queries here. The first is running in a query context whilst the second is essentially a `match_all` query executing in a filtered context. If your objective is simply to emulate the first query but by passing a JSON body you will need something like

```
GET 123.456.0.789:9200/stories/storyphrases/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "StoryText:'The boy sat quietly'"
        }
    }
}
```

To write this simple query using Nest you would use

```
var searchresults = client.Search<stories>(p => p.QueryString("StoryText:" + inputtext));
```

or in longer form

```
var searchresults = client.Search<stories>(p => p
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .Query("StoryText:" + inputtext)
            )
        )
    );
```

These both produce the same JSON body and send it to the `_search` endpoint. Assuming that `storyphrases` is your Elasticsearch type then you may also wish to include this in your C#.

```
var searchresults = client.Search<stories>(p => p
    .Index("stories")
    .Type("storyphrases")
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .Query("StoryText:" + inputtext)
            )
        )
    );
```

Having said all that and looking at your filtered query it should do what you expect according to my testing. Is your field definitely not analyzed? Can you post your mapping?

Comment: I updated my post to show my mappings and sorry for the delay in my reply.  I will try what you suggest and post back with answers.

Comment: Mapping looks good. Have you tried using the _indices_ API to see how the input text is analyzed? Using cURL: `curl -XGET "http://123.456.0.789:9200/stories/_analyze?field=StoryText " -d'The boy sat quietly'`

Comment: Hi Ceej....sorry again for the delay in my reply.  I tried what you have suggested and get the following response `{ "_index" : "stories, "_type": "storyphrases", "_id" : "_analyze", "found" : false}`. I also used your suggestion above, but am still returning multiple hits in my code for a single phrase.  I am perplexed.